# How to read the number of lines in a LARGE text file effeciently

Tags: lua

I have a large text file of ~750,000 lines that gets updated constantly every few seconds, and I want to be able to monitor the number of lines in real time. I am able to do that, but at a very heavy cost of response time.

```
function GetFileSize( filename )
  local fp = io.open( filename )
  if fp == nil then
    return nil
  end
  file = {}
  for line in fp:lines() do
    if (file[line] ~= line) then
      table.insert(file, line)
    end
  end
  d(table.size(file))
  local filesize = fp:seek( "end" )
  fp:close()
  return filesize
end
```

I'm trying to get two things, the size (bytes) and the number of lines.

However, filling the table up with 750,000 lines over and over, reading the file from top to bottom, constantly, causes quite a bit of processing time.

Is there a way to get both the file size in bytes, but also get the number of lines, without severely hindering my system.

Pretty much I'm guessing I have to create a permanent table outside of the function, where you read the file and add the lines to the table. However, I'm not sure how to stop it from duplicating itself every few seconds.

Should I just abandon the line count and stick with the byte return since that doesn't slow me down at all? or is there an efficient way to get both.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need the number of lines, and the not the actual content of the lines, you do not need to store them in a table.  Simply count them instead.

Comment: What do you store in the file? Will each line always be the same length? How accurate do you want to be? total_byte_count/byte_count_per_line would give you the number of lines if applicable.

Comment: @warspyking I don't need the information inside the file, just the line count with the least amount of processing time.

Comment: Please reread my comment. You misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the whole file at once and count the number of lines with `gsub`.  You'll have to test whether this is fast enough for you.

```
 t = f:read("*a")
 _,n = t:gsub("\n","")
```

Comment: I think this one require allocate 2 buffers for file content. May be use `t:gsub("\n","\n")`? May be it will not allocate new memory.

Answer (score 1):

To get the file size in bytes use [Lua Filesystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/).  For the number of lines you might want to use the `io.lines` iterator.  For better performance of the latter there is [a trick](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.1.html) described in »Programming in Lua«.

```
local file = arg[0] -- just use the source file for demo

-- Get the file size
local lfs = assert(require"lfs")
local attr = lfs.attributes(file)
print(attr.size)

-- Get number of lines
local count = 0
for line in io.lines(file) do
   count = count + 1
end
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest this solution. Which does not require read all large file.

```
local function char_count(str, ch)
  local n, p = 0
  while true do
    p = string.find(str, ch, p, true)
    if not p then break end
    n, p = n + 1, p + 1
  end
  return n
end

local function file_info(name, chunk_size)
  chunk_size = chunk_size or 4096
  local f, err, no = io.open(name, 'rb')
  if not f then return nil, err, no end
  local lines, size = 0, 0
  while true do
    local chunk = f:read(chunk_size)
    if not chunk then break end
    lines = lines + char_count(chunk, '\n')
    size = size + #chunk
  end
  f:close()
  return size, lines
end
```

But if you just need monitor one file and count lines in it may be just use any file monitor solution. I use one [based on LibUV](https://github.com/moteus/lua-spylog/blob/92b7b63c764d04571773769acbee7138c42ea4b3/src/filter/lib/spylog/monitor/file.lua#L11)